# Is there a way to reverse individual scrambled words in a string without changing the words' order in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to reverse a string without using the built-in reverse method to get something like this:

```
input: "hello, world"
output: "world hello,"
```

I've been able to reverse the string to "dlrow ,olleh" so the words are the in the order they should be, but I'm stuck on how to reverse the individual words.

Comment: Can you post the code you have written?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Comment: From one Cary to another, welcome to SO.

Comment: Cary, I see that for an answer (now deleted) that suggested `input.split.reverse.join(' ')` you left a comment "...I'm trying to do it without using the built in reverse method...". As `input.split` is an array, I infer that it is `Array#reverse` (as opposed to `String#reverse`) that is not to be used. You need to edit your question to make it clear that `Array#reverse` is not to be used.

Comment: @Jörg, I'm always mildly amused when I read, "Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service", because that's exactly what I see it as. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose

```
str = "Three blind mice"
```

Here are three ways you could obtain the desired result, `"mice blind Three"`, without using the method [Array#reverse](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-reverse).

**Split string, add index, use [Enumerable#sort_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) to sort array by index, join words**

```
str.split.each_with_index.sort_by { |_,i| -i }.map(&:first).join(' ')
```

The steps are as follows.

```
a = str.split
  #=> ["Three", "blind", "mice"] 
enum = a.each_with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["Three", "blind", "mice"]:each_with_index> 
b = enum.sort_by { |_,i| -i }
  #=> [["mice", 2], ["blind", 1], ["Three", 0]] 
c = b.map(&:first)
  #=> ["mice", "blind", "Three"] 
c.join(' ')
  #=> "mice blind Three"
```

We can see the elements that will be generated by `enum` and passed to `sort_by` by converting `enum` to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [["Three", 0], ["blind", 1], ["mice", 2]]
```

A disadvantage of this method is that it sorts an array, which is a relatively expensive operation. The next two approaches do not share that weakness.

**Split string, use [Array#values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-values_at) to extract words by index, highest to lowest join words**

```
arr = str.split
arr.values_at(*(arr.size-1).downto(0).to_a).join(' ')
```

The steps are as follows.

```
arr = str.split
  #=> ["Three", "blind", "mice"] 
a = arr.size-1
  #=> 2 
b = a.downto(0).to_a
  #=> [2, 1, 0] 
c = arr.values_at(*b)
  #=> ["mice", "blind", "Three"] 
c.join(' ')
  #=> "mice blind Three"
```

**Use [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) to create an enumerator, chain to [Enumerator#with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object), build string**

```
str.gsub(/\w+/).with_object('') { |word,s|
  s.prepend(s.empty? ? word : word + ' ') }
```

The steps are as follows.

```
enum1 = str.gsub(/\w+/)
  #=> #<Enumerator: "Three blind mice":gsub(/\w+/)> 
enum2 = enum1.with_object('')
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: "Three blind mice":
  #     gsub(/\w+/)>:with_object("")> 
enum2.each { |word,s| s.prepend(s.empty? ? word : word + ' ') }
  #=> "mice blind Three"
```

When `String#gsub` is called on `str` without a block it returns an enumerator (see doc). The enumerator generates, and passes to `with_object`, matches of its argument, `/\w+/`; that is, words. At this point `gsub` no longer performs character replacement. When called without a block it is convenient to think of `gsub` as being named `each_match`. We can see the values that `enum1` generates by converting it to an array (or execute [Enumerable#entries](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-entries) on `enum1`):

```
enum1.to_a
  #=> ["Three", "blind", "mice"]
```

Though Ruby has no such concept, it may be helpful to think of `enum2` as a *compound enumerator* (study the return value for `enum2 = enum1.with_object('')` above). It will generate the following values, which is will pass to [Enumerator#each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-each):

```
enum2.to_a
  #=> [["Three", ""], ["blind", ""], ["mice", ""]]
```

The second value of each of these elements is the initial value of the string that will be built and returned by `each`.

Let's now look at the first element element being generated by `enum2` and passed to the block:

```
word, s = enum2.next
  #=> ["Three", ""]
```

This first step is called [Array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition).

```
word
  #=> "Three" 
s #=> ""
```

The block calculation is then as follows.

```
s.empty?
  #=> true 
t = word
  #=> "Three" 
s.prepend(t)
  #=> "Three" 
s #=> "Three"
```

Now the second element is generated by `enum2` and passed to the block

```
word, s = enum2.next
  #=> ["blind", "Three"] 
word
  #=> "blind" 
s #=> "Three" 
s.empty?
  #=> false 
t = word + ' '
  #=> "blind " 
s.prepend(t)
  #=> "blind Three"
```

Notice that the value of second element of the array returned by `enum2.next`, the current value of `s`, has been updated to `"Three"`.

The processing of the third and final element generated by `enum2` (`["mice", "blind Three"]`) is similar, resulting in the block returning the value of `s`, `"mice blind Three"`.